Discrepancy Integrating $\frac{1}{x^2+1}$ through Complex Partial Fractions
I was looking at integrating arctangent's derivative through complex partial fractions and have found a discrepancy I'm struggling to justify.
We have
$$I=\int\frac{dx}{x^2+1}$$
The integrand may be expressed as $\frac{A}{x+i}+\frac{B}{x-i}$
Computing coefficients via residues, we have
$$A=\frac{1}{\frac{d}{dx}(x^2+1)}\biggr\rvert_{x=-i}=\frac{i}{2}$$
$$B=\frac{1}{\frac{d}{dx}(x^2+1)}\biggr\rvert_{x=i}=-\frac{i}{2}$$
This gives the following for $I$:
$$I=\frac{i}{2}\int\frac{1}{x+i}-\frac{1}{x-i}\;dx$$
Upon integrating, we see the following:
\begin{align}
I&=\frac{i}{2}\left[\ln|x+i|-\ln|x-i|\right]+C \\
&=\frac{i}{2}\ln\left|\frac{x+i}{x-i}\right|+C \\
&=-\frac{i}{2}\ln\left|\frac{x-i}{x+i}\right|+C
\end{align}
I aim to verify this using the logarithmic definition of arctangent, but the result is slightly different.
\begin{align}
f(x)&=\tan(x) \\
&=\frac{\sin(x)}{\cos(x)} \\
&=\cfrac{\cfrac{\exp(ix)-\exp(-ix)}{2i}}{\cfrac{\exp(ix)+\exp(-ix)}{2}} \\
&=-i\cdot\frac{\exp(2ix)-1}{\exp(2ix)+1} \\
&=-i+\frac{2i}{\exp(2ix)+1} \\
\implies x&=-i+\frac{2i}{\exp(2if^{-1}(x))+1} \\
\exp(2if^{-1}(x))+1&=-\frac{2i}{x+i} \\
\exp(2if^{-1}(x))&=\frac{-x+i}{x+i} \\
2if^{-1}(x)&=\ln\left(\frac{-x+i}{x+i}\right) \\
f^{-1}(x)&=-\frac{i}{2}\ln\left(\frac{-x+i}{x+i}\right) \\
\implies \arctan(x)&=-\frac{i}{2}\ln\left(\frac{-x+i}{x+i}\right)
\end{align}
How do I account for the slight discrepancy in the formula obtained via integration and the one obtained through the logarithmic definition? I'm assuming it has something to do with the absolute value, but I can't seem to put my finger on it.
Thanks.

$\ln|x+i|$ is not an antiderivative of $1/(x+i)$

One aspect to the problem is that $\int \frac{dx}{x} = \ln |x| + C$ is not exactly correct. More accurately, when we're working in real numbers and want to avoid taking logarithms of negative values $\ln x + C$ is an antiderivative to $\frac{1}{x}$ on the region $x > 0$, and $\ln (-x) + C$ is an antiderivative to it on $x < 0$, and $\ln |x| + C$ is an attempt to reconcile the two.
Once you get into the complex domain, though, absolute values behave differently as does the logarithm function, so you really should stick to using $\int \frac{dz}{z} = \log z + C$ as long as you avoid the point $z = 0$.
A second aspect, though, is that if we compare $\log \frac{z - i}{z + i}$ and $\log \frac{-z + i}{z + i}$, notice that we have:
$$\begin{eqnarray}\log \frac{z - i}{z + i} & = & \log \frac{-(-z + i)}{z + i} \\
& = & \log \left(-1 \times \frac{-z + i}{z + i} \right) \\
& = & \log \frac{-z + i}{z + i} + \log(-1) \end{eqnarray}$$
so the two functions only differ by a constant, and thus with the $-\frac{i}{2}$ factor included both are valid antiderivatives of $\frac{1}{1 + z^2}$. What I've done here is still not 100% valid because $\log$ is a multi-valued function but if you work through things properly with the complex logarithm function $\mathrm{Log}$ on properly defined regions it does work but with potentially slightly different constants showing up.

Thank you for the detailed explanation, I really appreciate it.
